# Distributing fonts with installer

Tags: installshield

When user installs my application, I am installing my fonts to the windows. However, when they uninstall it, the fonts also get uninstalled. How do I make sure that fonts dont get uninstalled.I am creating installer with InstallShield Professional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally your font is a Component, so if you set the font Component's `Permanent` option to `Yes` it should remain after uninstall. [Documentation](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/IHelpCompPermanent.htm) here, and it even explicitly mentions fonts.